# Create a Google Doc file directly in a Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

How do I create a Google document in a Google Drive folder?

I know that I can create a file in a folder like this.

```
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("A Folder")
folder.createFile("filename.file", "Some text")
```

But how I can create a **document** in a folder using Google Apps Script.

Comment: For anyone who landed here because of a search result but only wanted to learn how to construct a URL manually for this purpose, `https://docs.google.com/document/create?folder=1d4AX96kMR34J0iNGABrrNg8` works for me: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6437/save-a-link-to-create-new-document-in-google-docs?rq=1#comment76082_6488

Answer (score 26):

The other answer is correct but the file will exist in your folder *AND* in your "drive" folder (the root folder).

To avoid that, simply remove it from there !

**code :**

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name'),
      docFile = DriveApp.getFileById( doc.getId() );
  DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3°°°°°°°1lXWkk').addFile( docFile );
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile);
```

Answer (score 9):

With document it's a bit different, you first create it then move to the folder:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name'),
      docFile = DriveApp.getFileById( doc.getId() );

DriveApp.getFolderById(foldId).addFile( docFile );
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how to create a new Google Doc in a specific folder.  When the Doc is created, the mime type must be set.

Note that this code does ***NOT*** first create a Doc file, move it, and then delete the file in the Root Drive.  This code creates a new Google Doc type file directly in a folder.

You will need to use the Advanced Drive API.  It must be enabled in two places.

- From the code editor choose "Resources" and then choose, "Advanced Google services"
- Click the button for "Drive API" so that it is ON.
- Click the link: Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard.
- Search Drive API
- Choose Google Drive API from search list
- Enable the Drive API

### Code:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var doc,fileResource,folder,ID_of_newFile,multipleFolders,newFile,
      newDocName,rng,sh,ss,ssFile,ssID;

  var name = e.values[1];
  var kantoor = e.values[2];

  newDocName = 'Sleuteloverdracht ' + name;//Set the name of the new file

  rng = e.range;//Get range in the spreadsheet that received the data
  sh = rng.getSheet();//Get sheet tab
  ss = sh.getParent();//Get spreadsheet
  ssID = ss.getSheetId();//Get file ID of spreadsheet - Integer

  ssFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID);//Get the spreadsheet file in order to get the
    //folder to put the new file in
  multipleFolders = ssFile.getParents();//Get all parent folders of the spreadsheet file

  folder = multipleFolders.next();//Get the folder of the spreadsheet

  fileResource = {
    'title': newDocName,
    "parents": [{'id':folder.getId()}],  //<--By setting this parent ID to the 
    //folder's ID, it creates this file in the correct folder
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
  };

  newFile = Drive.Files.insert(fileResource);//Create the new document file
   // directly into the same folder as the spreadsheet
  ID_of_newFile = newFile.getId();

  //Logger.log(ID_of_newFile)

  doc = DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId());//Open the new file as a Google document

  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('Sleuteloverdracht ' + name);
  body.appendParagraph('Uw naam is '+ name + '\n' + 
    'U heeft de sleutel van kantoor '+ kantoor);
  doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Serge insas's answer helped me, but the methods are now deprecated in 2021. Here is what worked for me.

```
var folder = 'Your Folder Id'
var title = 'Your File Name'    
var doc = DocumentApp.create(title);
docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
docFile.moveTo(folder);
```

Comment: When you use '.moveTo' instead of '.makeCopy' you can save the trouble to delete the file in the root folder. '.moveTo' actually moves to file to your target folder:

`var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
docFile.moveTo(targetFolder);`

Comment: Updated the above to include Oliver's comment.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Kriggs answer.

To remove from the root folder:

`DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file)`

Otherwise, it will be in the root level **and** the new location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder ("A Folder");
var file = DriveApp.createFile ("filename.file", "Some text");
file.moveTo (folder);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the Drive App to create a copy of a Google document (e.g. a template)

use this:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileId).makeCopy(name, destination);
```